# Comparing 2 dates gives me 1 day less in comparison in IOS

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, nsdate, nsdatecomponents

I am trying to compare 2 Dates but in i am getting 1 day less

here is a snippet:

```
NSDateComponents* dateComponents = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];

[dateComponents setYear: 2014];
[dateComponents setMonth: 1];
[dateComponents setDay: 31];

NSCalendar* calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];

NSDate* otherDay = [calendar dateFromComponents: dateComponents];


NSDate * todaydate= [NSDate date];

if ([otherDay compare:todaydate]>= NSOrderedDescending)
{
    NSLog(@"In If other Date= %@ & Today = %@ ", otherDay,todaydate);
}else
{
    NSLog(@"I am in else other date= %@ and today = %@ ",otherDay, todaydate);
}
```

The Log i am getting is :

```
I am in else other date= 2014-01-30 18:30:00 +0000 and today = 2014-01-31 08:34:21 +0000
```

Why it's showing other **date = 30th jan 2014** ?

Comment: Reads like an off-by-1 error, but not being familiar with that aspect of the iOS framework, I can only hint at the solution. Try using earlierDate:, isEqual:, and laterDate: instead of compare: and see if the problem still manifests itself

Comment: I suppose the problem is the GMT offset

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set **timezone**  of `NSDateComponents` such like,

```
[dateComponents setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"GMT"]];
```

Or as **trojanfoe's** suggestion you can also set **timezone** of `NSCalendar` such like,

```
[calendar setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"GMT"]];
```

And To exact compare **otherDay** to **todaydate** please see answer of **Martin R** you need to set

> NSDate * todaydate;
>   [calendar rangeOfUnit:NSDayCalendarUnit startDate:&todaydate interval:NULL forDate:[NSDate date]];

From **Martin R's**  answer this is very useful.

Comment: You should probably also set that calendar in `dateComponents`, as well.  I am unable to reproduce the OP's problem, however, due to where I live.

Comment: No, I mean `[dateComponents setCalendar:calendar];` (changing the order of the code and getting the calendar first).

Comment: Sorry, but I do not think that this is the correct solution. By setting the timezone to GMT, you compute otherDay as "2014-01-31 00:00 +0000", which is "2014-01-31 05:30" in the Indian timezone. This is not correct if you want to check if today is 2014-01-31 in India. - So it "fixes" the "display problem" (which is not really a problem), but not the wrong comparison with "today".

Comment: @MartinR - Yes you are right, Thanks for improve my knowledge :)

Answer (score 2):

There are two different aspects in your question. First,

```
NSDateComponents* dateComponents = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
[dateComponents setYear: 2014];
[dateComponents setMonth: 1];
[dateComponents setDay: 31];
NSCalendar* calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
NSDate* otherDay = [calendar dateFromComponents: dateComponents];
```

computes `otherDay` as "2014-01-31 00:00" (in your time zone), and

```
NSDate *todaydate = [NSDate date];
```

computes `todaydate` as the current point in time, which *includes the hours, minutes
and seconds*, for example "2014-01-31 13:00:00" (in your time zone). Therefore

```
[otherDay compare:todaydate]
```

returns `NSOrderedAscending`: `otherDay` is *earlier* than `todaydate`!

What you probably want is to compute `todaydate` as the *start of the current day*
(today at 00:00). This can be done as

```
NSDate * todaydate;
[calendar rangeOfUnit:NSDayCalendarUnit startDate:&todaydate interval:NULL forDate:[NSDate date]];
```

And now `[otherDay compare:todaydate]` returns `NSOrderedSame`, as you expected.

---

The other aspect is the `NSLog` output. Printing a `NSDate` with `NSLog()`
prints the date according to GMT, and "2014-01-31 00:00" in your time zone is
*exactly the same time as* "2014-01-30 18:30:00 +0000" in GMT.

The output is *correct*, it just uses GMT instead of your local timezone for display.